# Documenting an XML-RPC service

Tags: documentation, xml-rpc

I'm writing an XML-RPC service that will be consumed by third parties and was wondering what the best way of documenting it would be.

As far as I can see, XML-RPC doesn't have any equivalent to SOAP's WSDL to provide a description of the service, so presumably it's something I will have to document by hand?

So far I've come accross examples such as that found [here](http://technorati.com/developers/ping/) and [here](http://www.sixapart.com/developers/xmlrpc/movable_type_api/) where documentation basically consists of an example call with place holders for data.

Is there any better method than this that I'm missing?
Thanks.

Comment: First link is dead; second link redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [XML-RPC Introspection](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/introspection.html). It is about the closest thing to a standard that you are going to find.  XML-RPC does lend itself to simple documents of input/output descriptions.  If you want something that can be processed programatically, then implement or enable introspection.